# Reduce motion but reserve 3 finger swipe-up mission control animation?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, mojave, accessibility

[image]

In macOS Accessibility settings, there is an option named "Reduce motion", check this on will disable most animations in macOS,

and 3 finger swipe-up to show mission-control animation will became a fade-in/out animation

I want to enable reduce motion to disable some animations but preserve the original 3 finger swipe-up animation,

Is there any way to do this?